# How can I sort an ArraySeq of List by their second element?

Tags: scala

i have to sort all Zones in europe by length.

```
val strefy: Seq[String] = java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs.toSeq
val y = strefy.map(el =>el.split("/").toList).filter(el => el.head == "Europe")
println(y) returns => ArraySeq(List(Europe, Amsterdam), List(Europe, Andorra)......
```

and now i would like to sort it by lenght. I tried with `sortBy(_._2).lenght` but it does not work with Lists i guess. It is possible to do it without mapping List to single element? `.map(el => el(1))`

Answer (score 2):

`._2` is for second element in tuple, to get second element in the list you can use parenthesis:

```scala
val y = strefy.map(el =>el.split("/").toList).filter(el => el.head == "Europe")
  .sortBy(_(1).length)
```

or safer option - `lift`:

```scala
val y = strefy.map(el =>el.split("/").toList).filter(el => el.head == "Europe")
  .sortBy(_.lift(1).map(_.length))
```